# PHP header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" not working (nginx)

Tags: php, nginx, header

I have a very stranger behaviour when trying to set the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials on my pages to allow CORS.

To sum-up: my "Allow-Credentials" header sent with PHP seems to be taken into account **only** if the same header is sent by the server itself... in which case the header becomes "true, true" which is not an accepted value...

I'm using Laravel and have a middleware that adds the relevant headers to the relevant pages:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: mysite.test'));
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Authorization, Origin');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

When my page tries to send an Ajax request, the browser console outputs the following:

```
(...) The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

After trying a few things to debug, I added the header to the nginx conf itself:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";
```

And that's where I feel really helpless.. the output of the browser is now:

```
(...) The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is 'true, true' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

The same code works perfectly fine on another server with same .conf file for nginx.. Any idea where I can look to figure all this out?

Comment: Does the other server have different nginx version?

Comment: Nope.. both nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)